# Remove empty directories and directories which contain only specific file (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file which remove all empty directories and directories which contain only specific file (.svn).Thank you very much for any help.

Example :

```
Folder1                       -- folder conatins subfolders with some files, not remove
     Folder2                  -- empty folder, folder should be deleted
     Folder3                  -- folder contains only .svn, folder should be deleted
           .svn
     Folder4                  -- folder contains subfolder with file, not remove
           Folder41           -- folder contains some file, not remove
                somefile.dat
     Folder5                  -- folder contains some file, not remove 
           .svn
           somefile.dat
     Folder6                  -- folder contains empty subfolders, folder should be deleted
           Folder61           -- folder contains only specific file, folder should be deleted
                .svn
```

Result:

```
Folder1
     Folder4    
           Folder41
                somefile.dat
     Folder5
           .svn
           somefile.dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised at how little code this takes. The biggest trick is to use `SORT /R` on the output of `DIR /B /S /AD` so that you can process the child nodes prior to processing the parent nodes of the folder hierarchy.

I've quickly tested the code, but please test yourself in a safe manner.

This 1st version assumes `".SVN"` is the full file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| sort /r') do (
  dir /b "%%A" | findstr /livx ".svn" >nul || rd /s /q "%%A"
)
```

The 2nd version is only slightly modified in case you meant `"*.SVN"`. Only one FINDSTR option is changed.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| sort /r') do (
  dir /b "%%A" | findstr /live ".svn" >nul || rd /s /q "%%A"
)
```

**Update: 2012-11-06**

I just realized that the above solution(s) can be defeated if a non-empty folder is named `.SVN`. The code should remove folders that are either empty or only contain a file named `.SVN`. It should not remove a folder if it contains a non-empty folder named `.SVN`.

Below is a fix for the first solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| sort /r') do (
  dir /b "%%A"|findstr /livx ".svn" >nul||>nul 2>&1 dir /b /ad .svn||rd /s /q "%%A"
)
```

And here is a fix for the second solution

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /ad ^| sort /r') do (
  dir /b "%%A"|findstr /live ".svn" >nul||>nul 2>&1 dir /b /ad *.svn||rd /s /q "%%A"
)
```

Comment: Aaaand the usual caution applies with `for /f`: This will break with the console set to raster fonts and Unicode file names ;-). Not that I'm telling you anything new there, I guess, given that you know more about batches than me :)

Comment: @Joey - Thanks. Yes, I had seen you report issues with Unicode before, but no, I hadn't thought about it in this case. I don't think I have ever run into a Unicode file name before, so it's good you provided the warning.

Comment: It works fine. I'm trying to write the script during last three days, so thank you very much!